Preventing eggy sous vide water with Crème Brûlée
Crème Brûlée is a staple sous vide recipe in our household, but cooking them in Mason jars (even using expensive high quality ones) inevatibly leads to some leakage from the pots into the water. Apart from the horrible eggy smelling water, this requires a descale cycle of my water circulator.
The ziploc bag method is OK, but it is a faff equally measuring out the desert into the pots afterwards.
To prevent this, could I vacumn seal the pots to prevent leakage and if so, would I need to adjust the cooking time or temperature at all?
[Added as per request of @Questor]
This is identical to the type of jar I am using.


I don't understand how you are leaking. If the lids are tight you really shouldn't have that problem.

All the guides I have followed have said to only tighten the lids until finger tight. My understanding of that is to screw the lid on until it just stops an no more. I might get another 10-20 degrees or so of a turn, if that. I certainly wouldn't consider the lids loose, and there has been a strong seal between the rubber coated lid and the glass. Strangely though, there is little trace of water inside the jars but the sous-vide water itself is cloudy.

I have just had a thought, I wonder if just one of the jars has a bad seal/leak, that would account for the lack of moisture in the other jars. Not having checked the consistency of all the pots might be the reason I've missed that one.

Why not just fill the water to the level just below the neck?

Not easy, my circulator is very tall and the bath is deep. I could try putting something in the container to lift them up though.

Can you include a picture of your jar? I am picturing a meson jar with a canning lid... Which is designed to let things out when you heat the jar so that as the jar cools the jar will seal using negative pressure.. TLDR: I don't think its possible to stop the leak with that kind of jar.

Have done, @Questor.

I second what @Questor was saying, those jars are designed to work exactly as they are (venting slightly when heated). Tightening more or using lids that don't have two parts might prevent that, but it also might cause excess pressure to build up inside the jars.

As others said in comments, the problem is the lid: it's a canning lid. By design, once you heat the jar and pressure builds up the lid will allow air (and the jar's contents if it's full enough) to escape, to create a seal using negative pressure.
You can either use a different lid, or you could put the jars on top of a rack (or anything else) to make sure the lid is above water and you reach the minimum water level for the sous vide circulator.

I’m not sure I follow. Are you saying that the leakage occurs specifically because the jars are over-filled and the custard expands during cooking, overflowing the rim? So in this case, we would expect there to be custard residue on the inside of the lids?

Ah, you have hit the nail on the head there, @Sneftel and completed the puzzle. Indeed, each pot had just a smidgen of custard residue on the lids. The pots themselves are not overfilled (probably about 2/3rds and nowhere near the lid) but the expansion of the custard during cooking appears to be the culprit.

Thank you everyone for your contributions. I've decided to invest in a large Mason jar that is taller than the water level when the bath is full. Due to the long throat on my circulator, and depth of the bath, raising the pots up would be tricky.
